# is there another way i can write this? i only know the print function,but i can not seem to get it like the example

Tags: python, python-2.7

i can not seem to get the same print function as the example
i have used the basic print but it wont give me what i am looking for, also the commas don not seem to divide it

python 2.7

```
print "NUCLEAR CORE UNSTABLE!!!, Quarantine is in effect. , Surrounding hamlets will be evacuated. , Anti-radiationsuits and iodine pills are mandatory."
```

---

[image]

Comment: You may want to read up on [string literals](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html), especially linefeed `\n`.Could be very helpful in this situation

Comment: Just put the `print` statement in a function and call that function three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `print` *statement*, not function, and there are several ways to do it:

This uses a triple quoted string to preserve newlines:

```
def printit():
    print """NUCLEAR CORE UNSTABLE!!!
Quarantine is in effect.
Surrounding hamlets will be evacuated.
Anti-radiationsuits and iodine pills are mandatory.
    """
```

To run it 3 times just:

```
for i in range(3):
    printit()
```

This uses multiple `print` statements:

```
def printit():
    print "NUCLEAR CORE UNSTABLE!!!"
    print "Quarantine is in effect."
    print "Surrounding hamlets will be evacuated."
    print "Anti-radiationsuits and iodine pills are mandatory.\n"
```

This uses just one line with embedded newlines:

```
def printit():
    print "NUCLEAR CORE UNSTABLE!!!\nQuarantine is in effect.\nSurrounding hamlets will be evacuated.\nAnti-radiationsuits and iodine pills are mandatory.\n"
```

However, you mentioned `print` *function* and complained about the comma separators not doing anything, so:

```
from __future__ import print_function
def printit():
    print ("NUCLEAR CORE UNSTABLE!!!",
           "Quarantine is in effect.",
           "Surrounding hamlets will be evacuated.",
           "Anti-radiationsuits and iodine pills are mandatory.\n",
           sep="\n")
```

Personally I prefer this one.  You could put it all on one line, but that makes the code difficult to read and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

```
class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

print bcolors.WARNING + "Warning: No active frommets remain. Continue?" 
      + bcolors.ENDC
```

This is a code snippet that I found online and works!

```
    print bcolors.WARNING + "NUCLEAR CORE UNSTABLE!!!" + bcolors.ENDC + '''\n Quarantine is in effect. \n
Surrounding hamlets will be evacuated. , Anti-radiationsuits and iodine pills are mandatory.'''
```

You can also use \t to put in a tab space

Comment: I believe OP is asking about printing multiple lines. No mention of color.

Comment: I think he wants bold text (see the image), so this class indeed does implement that, but sure, I'll elaborate my answer

Comment: no sorry,this is not it, more like a print function but it has to come out like in the example,same text everything. but very much appriciate your time and effort

Comment: The code is not portable, the characters used depend on the terminal, or emulator in use.  It would not display correctly, for example, on Windows.